iframe being being blocked by CSP in iOS Cordova app
We're running an app on Cordova version 12.0.0 and cordova-ios 7.1.0.
We have an iframe which works on multiple browsers in web and in an Android app.
But it doesn't work in our app on ios, other iframes do work however on ios.
The reason this particular iframe isn't working is due to the following csp violation...

Refused to load https://example.com because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.

If I check the frame-ancestor value coming back for the actual site we're using in this iframe it's set to...
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *;
So unless I'm misunderstanding this, whilst it is a bit off an odd setting, that's saying allow iframes from same domain or any domain.
So basically any domain can embed this content.
So in theory this should be working on ios as well, I'm assuming this is some quirk to do with Cordova? Although I'm not sure how I can resolve this.
We have this set in our config.xml also...
  <allow-navigation href="*" />

If you need any other info about our configuration let me know.

What's your "scheme" and "hostname" values  ?

Scheme is 'example:/' then also in the config.xml we have          for hostname it's 'app.example.cloud'

Noticed we also have this         

It should be  not Scheme

Okay will give that a go, but in that case why do other iframes work yet this one doesn't?

Should say we're also using cordova plugin ionic webview and checking the documentation it is Scheme not scheme.

Sorry can't help you any further, I don't touch ionic
